# transform: translateX() issue for kendo-mobile-switch on ngDialog in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using `kendo-mobile-switch` in my AngularJS project. It works fine for pages. But when I am trying to use it on ngDialog I have an issue with `transform: translateX()` component on `ngDialog` modal. 
Instead of moving to 27 pixels right it just stays on the same place.

I tried to get rid from `ngDialog.min.css` `ngdialog` class to fix that issue, I removed all `ngdialog` css classes on my module but issue still here. I cannot toggle my `kendo-mobile-switch` to 27 pixels right

here is my code :

```
<div  ng-controller="navBarLimitedUseKeyCtrl" focus-group="" focus-group-head="stop" focus-group-tail="loop">
    <div kendo-mobile-switch
         k-on-label="'YES'" k-off-label="'NO'" ng-model="var.oneShot"
         k-on-change="onChangeOneShot()" data-qaid="chk-oneShot-default">
    </div>
</div>
```

Did anybody have a similar issue with `transform: translateX()` for `kendo-mobile-switch` on `ngDialog` in AngularJS? How was it fixed?

That code appears for me like that :
[image]

The same issue which I reported. i am using Google Chrome Version 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be caused by some custom CSS as this snippet does not show any issues.

```js
var app = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngDialog', 'kendo.directives']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ngDialog) {
  $scope.clickToOpen = function() {
    ngDialog.open({
      appendTo: '.main',
      overlay: false,
      template: `
         <div kendo-mobile-switch
         k-on-label="'YES'" 
         k-off-label="'NO'" 
         ng-model="var.oneShot"
         k-on-change="onChangeOneShot()" 
         data-qaid="chk-oneShot-default">
         </div>
         <input type="checkbox" />
        `,
      plain: true,
      className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.4.0/css/ngDialog.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.4.0/css/ngDialog-theme-default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.4.0/css/ngDialog-theme-plain.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.4.0/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="exampleApp">
  <div class="main" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="clickToOpen()">Open</button>
    <div kendo-mobile-switch k-on-label="'YES'" k-off-label="'NO'" ng-model="var.oneShot" k-on-change="onChangeOneShot()" data-qaid="chk-oneShot-default">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem which I have with my ngDialog module and kendo-mobile-switch. kendo-mobile-switch works fine outside ngDialog and have the same issue inside ngDialog modal. I removed all css except kendo.default.mobile.min.css but still have the problem inside ngDialog. Do you have an idea what is the cause of that issue? Thank you

Comment: What specifically is 27 pixels out of alignment? This appears to look OK to me.

Comment: Appears is OK for me too but when I click on toggle, it doesn't pass to "yes". Toggle is still on "no". I added screenshot to my question above.

Comment: I see the issue now. I updated the snippet to compare the switch inside and outside the dialog. It appears that then Kendo Switch may be using some JavaScript to `translate` the switch slide effect and this fails when inside the dialog. I would check the Kendo forums.

Comment: By the way, the control does respond to clicks and toggles its class from on to off. It is just the `translateX` which always stays at 0. You may be able to capture the event and override the translation somehow.

Comment: Thank you very much, Christopher. I will try to override AngularJS translation.